# How to indent the first line of a paragraph in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, text-indent

I'm using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) and I want to indent just the first line of the paragraph. What I've done before is click "Source" and edit the `<p>` style to include `text-indent:12.7mm;`, but when I click "Source" again to go back to the normal editor, my changes are gone and I have no idea why.

My preference would be to create a custom toolbar button, but I'm not sure how to do so or where to edit so that clicking a custom button would edit the `<p>` with the style attribute I want it to have.

Comment: In the mean time, is there configuration to allow the source to be editable? I was thinking maybe that is my problem with my source edits disappearing.

Comment: Why don't you style it with css instead? `#content p:first-child{ text-indent:12.7mm; }`

Comment: And how do I do that in CKEDITOR?

Comment: @Ervald Why did you not add that as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on which version of CKE you use, your changes most likely disappear because ether the `style` attribute or the `text-indent` style is not allowed in the content. This is due to the Allowed Content Filter feature of CKEditor, read more here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter

Like Ervald said in the comments, you can also use CSS to do this without adding the code manually - however, your targeting options are limited. Either you have to target all paragraphs or add an id or class property to your paragraph(s) and target that. Or if you use a selector like `:first-child` you are restricted to always having the first element indented only (which might be what you want, I don't know :D).

To use CSS like that, you have to add the relevant code to `contents.css`, which is the CSS file used in the Editor contents and also you have to include it wherever you output the Editor contents.

---

In my opinion the best solution would indeed be making a plugin that places an icon on the toolbar and that button, when clicked, would add or remove a class like "indentMePlease" to the currently active paragraph. Developing said plugin is quite simple and well documented, see the excellent example at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1 - if you need more info or have questions about that, ask in the comments :)

If you do do that, you again need to add the "indentMePlease" style implementation in contents.css and the output page.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a way to indent the first line without using style, because I'm using iReport to generate automatic reports. Jasper does not understand styles. So I assign by jQuery an onkeydown method to the main iframe of CKEditor 4.6 and I check the TAB and Shift key to do and undo the first line indentation.

```
// TAB
    $(document).ready(function(){
        startTab();
    });

    function startTab() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var $iframe_document;
            var $iframe;
            $iframe_document = $('.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contents();
            $iframe = $iframe_document.find('body');

            $iframe.keydown(function(e){
                event_onkeydown(e);
            });

        },300); 
    }

    function event_onkeydown(event){
        if(event.keyCode===9) { // key tab
            event.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(function(){
                var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'], //get your CKEDITOR instance here
                    range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0],
                    startNode = range.startContainer,
                    element = startNode.$,
                    parent;

                if(element.parentNode.tagName != 'BODY') // If you take an inner element of the paragraph, get the parentNode (P)
                    parent = element.parentNode;
                else // If it takes BODY as parentNode, it updates the inner element
                    parent = element;

                if(event.shiftKey) { // reverse tab
                    var res = parent.innerHTML.toString().split('&nbsp;');
                    var aux = [];
                    var count_space = 0;

                    for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
                        // console.log(res[i]);
                        if(res[i] == "")
                            count_space++;
                        if(count_space > 8 || res[i] != "") {
                            if(!count_space > 8)
                                count_space = 9;
                            aux.push(res[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    parent.innerHTML = aux.join('&nbsp;');
                }
                else { // tab
                    var spaces = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    parent.innerHTML = spaces + parent.innerHTML;
                }
            },200);
        }
    }
```